# VB - ASC(Input (1, #1)) returning wrong value '63'

Tags: excel, vba

I have this VBA code running on Excel 2013 on Win8.1

I try to read a file, that when using a hex editor, show the first byte as "E5", but when I read it using the basic OPEN > INPUT functions, it fails to return the correct ASCII value and always gives me a "63".  I tried using AscW but it does not solve the problem

sub a()

Open "filename" For Binary Access Read As #1

msgbox asc(Input(1,#1))

end sub

Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
Sub dy()

Open "filename" For Binary As #1

 MsgBox Asc(Input(1, #1))




End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding Prabhat, unfortunately this does not work.  I still have 63 returned instead of the correct value.